# Darle valor a una variable con mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

Bueno lo que necesito y no puedo hacer es cargar de la base de datos las variables "categoria" y "nombreskin" y se van a ordenar de forma desentiende por el id (estuve buscando en google y esto me funcionó)

```
$consulta = "SELECT categoria, nombreskin FROM stock ORDER by id DESC LIMIT 0,5";
        if ($resultado = $con->query($consulta)) {

        while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
            printf ("%s [%s]\n\n", $fila["categoria"], $fila["nombreskin"]);
        }
```

Pero no necesito usar printf sino necsito guardarlo en variables Ej

```
$id0categoria = $fila["categoria"];
$id1categoria = $fila["categoria"];
$id2categoria = $fila["categoria"];
$id3categoria = $fila["categoria"];
$id4categoria = $fila["categoria"];
```

y que cada $idcategoria corresponda a la fila

pero no me funciona cuando imprimo $id1categoria se me imprimen las 5 categorías ¿como hago para seleccionar que fila quiero guardar en cada variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## no se para que quieras hacer esto pero no es lo mas recomendable.

si aun deseas hacerlo.

seria asi:

```
$consulta = "SELECT categoria, nombreskin FROM stock ORDER by id DESC LIMIT 0,5";

if ($resultado = $con->query($consulta)) {
   while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
    // asignamos a $tmp el string "id0categoria", "id1categoria" etc...
    // la sinxatis `${}` el simbolo de $ se usa para analizar el mayor numero de 
 // caracteres que se pase dentro del delimitador {} para formar un nombre de variable válido
    $tmp = "id${contador}categoria"; 
    // ahora convertimos ese string a variable con `${}`
    // donde `$` es para definir una variable y "{}" evalua lo que caracteres
    // en este caso el valor de $tmp  => "id0categoria", "id1categoria" etc...
    ${$tmp} = $fila["categoria"];
    $contador++;
    //printf ("%s [%s]\n\n", $fila["categoria"], $fila["nombreskin"]);
   }
}

echo($id0categoria);
echo($id1categoria);
echo($id2categoria);
echo($id3categoria);
////// resto de variables ////
```